# Implement a Walker with custom object rather than Wordpress database object

Tags: customization, menus, walker

I am trying to implement a Custom Walker to navigate through a hierarchy of objects. When I do a `var_dump` on the `$item` variable in the `start_el` function I see a wordpress database object (blog, page, etc.) and not my custom Data Object.

How do I set up the Walker to accept my custom object for Menu hierarchy and navigation?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 1):

May not be exactly what you are after, but you could take a look at the [Bootstrap Nav Walker implementation](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker).

In the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker), there's also an example for [manually calling your own walker](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker#Using_Walker_Manually) class which may be worth a read if you haven't done so already.

```
class Walker_Quickstart_Menu extends Walker {

    // Tell Walker where to inherit it's parent and id values
    var $db_fields = array(
        'parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 
        'id'     => 'db_id' 
    );

    /**
     * At the start of each element, output a <li> and <a> tag structure.
     * 
     * Note: Menu objects include url and title properties, so we will use those.
     */
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $output .= sprintf( "\n<li><a href='%s'%s>%s</a></li>\n",
            $item->url,
            ( $item->object_id === get_the_ID() ) ? ' class="current"' : '',
            $item->title
        );
    }
}
```

And then call the walker:

```
// 1. Fetch the menu (we'll assume it has an id of 2)...
$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object(2);

// 2. Create an empty $menu_items array
$menu_items = array();

// 3. Get menu objects (this is our tree structure)
if ( $menu && ! is_wp_error($menu) && empty($menu_items) ) {
    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu );
}

// 4. Create a new instance of our walker...
$walk = new Walker_Quickstart_Menu();

// 5. Walk the tree and render the returned output as a one-dimensional array
print_r( $walk->walk( $menu_items, -1 ) );
```